# SharePoint 2016 Search Fileshare content source crawled successfully but no files show when searched

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, search-results, searchserviceapplication, content-source

i have configured SharePoint 2016 Search File share content source, this has crawled successfully with 350 files shown. Search results find files from the existing SP sites/libs, but no files are found when searching for known files from the file share Content source. The URL view in log shows the files, if i create a result query against that Content source it does not find anything as well when i test this.
I have checked permissions on the account used to search for the files against the file share and it can read the files.
I have configured before against a fileserver externally and had no problem but I'm stumped with this. Any help greatly appreciated.